# Setting DNS with CNames and A Records

Tags: dns, nameserver

I'm trying to help someone out with their domain.  The Name Servers are on Enom.  They need the subdomain m.example.com to point somewhere specific for a mobile version of the site.  In order to set a CName or A record I have to park the domain.  I parked the domain and set the DNS as following:

www -> CNAME -> (Previous Name Server)
m -> CNAME -> (Server URL)

My assumption was I could put the previous name server in as a cname for the www, but that appears to not be the case.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

CNAME records don't point to URLs. They just point to hostnames.

```
VALID: www.example.com -> asdf.example.net  
WRONG: www.example.com -> http://asdf.example.net
```

A CNAME is a Canonical Name record, ie an alias. So in the example, a user entering `www.example.com` will get the DNS Records associated with `asdf.example.com`.

Comment: That is how I did it.  I'm assuming it's not working because I'm trying to use a nameserver instead of a specific website url.

Comment: Um, I don't think you read what I wrote... Try again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should just point directly to the hostname you want in the URL.  If your host you want to server the contnet has the URL `http://www.example.net`,  then you would create CNAME for `m.example.com` that returns `www.example.net`.   You should have no CNAME pointing to name servers.

The server that is providing the content needs to configured to handle requests for `m.example.com`.  If not, it will serve up content from its default domain.  It is possible to configure servers so that the default domain only provides error responses.